# Find linear transformation to make different correlation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, linear-transformations

I have random vector $\xi = (\xi_1, \xi_2)^T$ whitch PDF is $p(x, y) = c e^{-(x-y)^{2} + xy}$. My goal is to find matrix $A$ so that vector $\eta = A\xi$ will have correlation $-\frac{1}{2}$ between components.

$$p(x, y) = c e^{-(x-y)^{2} + xy} = c e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2x^2+2y^2 - 6xy)} = c e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x,y)^T\Sigma(x,y)},$$
where
$$\Sigma =\begin{pmatrix}  2&-3\\-3&  2\end{pmatrix}.$$
So that is not normal distribution. What distribution it is? How should i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PDF is not PDF: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-y)^2 + xy} \,dx\, dy =  
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-\frac{3}{2}y)^2 + \frac{5}{4}y^2} \,dx\, dy = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2 + \frac{5}{4}v^2} \,du\, dv = \infty$
Thus it is incorrect task.